# Apex Batch Callouts

Tags: apex, batch, integration, callout, schedulebatch

Everytime an record is created in salesforce by external system we need to send the same record with updated values to the external system. When we receive bulk of records say some 10000 or more. I want to process the bulk of records in a batch and make a callout. External system service looks like it will handle only one record. For one parent record and there will be multiple child records. If Salesforce wants to send the bulk of parent records then the external system must also be written to handle bulk of parent instead of one single parent. Is my understanding correct? If I get bulk of records then how can i handle it as per the below json?

**Sample Json Request for the service:**

```
{
  "Account": {
    "Name": {
      "CompanyName": "sample string 1",
      "Place": "sample string 2"
    },
    "Contacts": [
      {
        "From": "sample string 1",
        "To": "sample string 2"
      },
      {
        "From": "sample string 1",
        "To": "sample string 2"
      }
    ],
    "Opportunities": [
      {
        "From": "sample string 1",
        "To": "sample string 2"
      },
      {
        "From": "sample string 1",
        "To": "sample string 2"
      }
    ],
    "Activities": [
      {
        "From": "sample string 1",
        "To": "sample string 2"
      },
      {
        "From": "sample string 1",
        "To": "sample string 2"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes your correct. The external system needs to be able to handle it. Do you have control of the external system? If so you can simply have it query for the records. There are multiple ways to slice it. As for your last question it is unclear to me. Are you asking how to structure a json array of Accounts?

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. My second question is , because the external system accepts one parent record for one request then when in salesforce we try to send it in a batch we will get callout issue. So how to handle it?

Comment: You can send a call out in a batch. I fact I think it is now 1 or 2 hundred. If you are having trouble with the batch post the code and specifics of the issue